# how to filter dataframe for specific Dates and Name in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter my Dataframe by 2 columns one is for date and other one is for name.

How can I filter out data from previous month only?. So if I run code today it will filter out data for previous month.

So date columns contains values

```
as(year,month,date): [202006, 202005, 202007,202107,20200601, 20200630 ]
```

etc.(Note that in some, date is absent)

And while filtering this, I also want to filter 2nd columns in which I only want to take those name which contains specific keywords.

Example:

```
Data=[[202006,Fuel oil],[202007, crude oil],[20200601, palm oil],[20200805, crude oil],[202007, Marine fuel]]
```

If i run the code it will automatically give me previous month's data and name which contains "oil" word.

Comment: Ca you be more specific, what is previous month data? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @jezrael Edited question. Please check. I need to perform this every month. So if I perform this in July, It should give me filtered data only from June.

Comment: Last month means, In the above example, it will return row which contain only [202006,Fuel oil] and [20200601, palm oil]. Here 2020 is year and 06 is month(Previous month because current month is 07).

Comment: I understand now, added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert dates to datetimes, here is used 2 formats of dates by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with different `format`s and `errors='coerce'`, missing values are replaced by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'date':[202006, 202005, 202007,202107,20200601, 20200630 ],
                  'fuel':['Fuel oil','crude oil','fuel oil',
                          'castor oil','crude oil', 'fuel']})

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = d1.fillna(d2)
print (df)
        date        fuel
0 2020-06-01    Fuel oil
1 2020-05-01   crude oil
2 2020-07-01    fuel oil
3 2021-07-01  castor oil
4 2020-06-01   crude oil
5 2020-06-30        fuel
```

Then values are filtered by monh periods - [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) compared with subtracted today month for first condition, then is chained by `&` for bitwise `AND` second condition by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now').to_period('M')

df = df[df['date'].dt.to_period('M').eq(now - 1) & df['fuel'].str.contains('oil')]
print (df)
        date       fuel
0 2020-06-01   Fuel oil
4 2020-06-01  crude oil
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':[202006, 202005, 202007, 202107, 20200601, 20200630],
    'fuel':['Fuel oil', 'crude oil', 'fuel oil', 'castor oil', 'crude oil', 'fuel']})
```

Then you can do the following code to filter it:

```
import time

# finding previous month and year
current_year= time.gmtime().tm_year
current_month= time.gmtime().tm_mon

# Adding a check if the current month is January
if current_month!=1:
    prev_month= current_month-1 
else:
    prev_month=12
    current_year -= 1

# extracting month,year info from the date column by converting it into strings

df[df.date.apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[4:6])==prev_month and int(str(x)[:4])== current_year) & df.fuel.apply(lambda x: 'oil' in x)]
```

Note:
`df.date.apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[4:6])` extracts the month info which i use to compare with previous month and filter.
`df.fuel.apply(lambda x: 'oil' in x)` sees which element has the word oil in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But just one problem It also filters 6th month data from different years like 202106, 202206, 202306 etc.Can you just keep data for 2020 only

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I have changed the code to incorporate it. I also realized that if the current month is Jan then the code would break. So modified the code slightly to give previous year's Dec month in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataframe is called 'dataframe', and the date-column is the first column and the 'name' column is the second,
you can use this simple for loop to filter all the items and add them to a new dataframe.

```
dataframe_filter = pd.DataFrame()

month = 202006 #filter by this month
key_word = 'oil' #filter by this keyword

for i in range(0, len(dataframe)):
    if dataframe.iloc[i,0] == month or dataframe.iloc[i,0]//100 == month: #date that doesnt includes day or date that includes day
        if key_word in dataframe.iloc[i,1]: 
           dataframe_filter[i] = (dataframe.iloc[i]) #set to new column in dataframe_filter (remember to transpose dataframe to change back to correct format)

dataframe_filter = dataframe_filter.transpose()  #transpose dataframe
```